# Gathering Crash logs off Samsung Galaxy Devices

Tags: android, logging, crash

I have been testing some applications on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Samsung Galaxy S. When the app crashes, I can't seem to gather the crash logs. I have tried many of the apps in the Android Market that are suppose to gather the logs, but none of them seem to work. When I go to email myself the logs, the file is contains nothing. So I'm wondering if this is a Samsung thing, and if so what recommendation does anyone has.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Galaxy series are on Android 4.1 and higher, in which case [the only app that can get log data is the app that logged it](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html), not a third-party app. Hence, the right way to get crash logs is to have that be baked into your app (e.g., via [ACRA](http://acra.ch/)) or to rely on the crash data supplied to the Play Store.